Configure Yocto Output zip extension type
I previously had yocto images being generated with .gz zip types
core-image-imx8mn-var-som-20240426072843.rootfs.tar.gz
core-image-imx8mn-var-som-20240426070451.rootfs.wic.gz

but ever since I updated my yocto flavour I am now producing .zst zip types for the image output. Is there a way to configure the zip type that is used?
core-image-imx8mn-var-som-20240426072843.rootfs.tar.zst
core-image-imx8mn-var-som-20240426072843.rootfs.wic.zst

My Yocto Flavor is Mickledore 4.2

Add the following line in local.conf to generate wic.gz compressed image.
IMAGE_FSTYPES += " wic.gz"

You can also add other image types that you want to build here like wic.bz2, wic, ext4 etc

I added this to my layer.conf but it still only outputs wic.zst and tar.zst...

Found the local.conf I had to add to in ~/var-fslc-yocto/build_xwaland/conf/local.conf
I had to also change the syntax based on my yocto version and add the *.zst extensions or else it would give me errors
IMAGE_FSTYPES:append = " tar.zst wic.zst wic.gz tar.gz"
Thanks for the help.
